# Choose best authentication and authorization option for Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin, jwt

We have our own existing we portal in ASP.NET MVC, now our one of the customer do not want to use our portal as separate tool, instead they want to consume our feature via WEB API and consume it on their side.

Now I want to implement authentication and authorization in web API, I did google to find my question's answer, but didn't get it.

I am confused in below points.

1. Is it best choice to OWIN the default implementation which Microsoft provide? or some custom implementation?
2. What are the advantage and disadvantage to use OWIN in terms of security?
3. When to Use JWT (Json Web token) and OWIN?
4. Or any other implementation which help to create more secured web API?

Looking for all expert's valuable to input to help me to decide.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something similar. This is how we work: we have our application (MVC app) which permits us to login. Logging in uses a separate mvc project (our STS) which handles all user authentication. When our login and password is posted correctly, we generate a JWT which is returned to the MVC app. Back on the application side, we decode our token and build up the claims in it in an asp.net application cookie. 
We also have a separate project containing our WebApi REST methods. Those can only be called by using the JWT generated by our STS. We elaborated this more with a custom attribute so we can set permissions on specific permission or role claims that are in the token.

For creating all of this, i was helped very much using these series of articles: http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

In terms of architecture this is in my opinion 'how it should be' but i am not an expert in this.

So summary:

- Web Application - application cookie to authenticate/authorize
- Calling WebApi Rest methods - using the JWT to authenticate/authorize
- Separate STS which takes in POSTS to authenticate and generate JWTs